# NestJS Multiple ack parameters in @SubscribeMessage functions

Tags: socket.io, nestjs, nestjs-socket.io

In NestJS with socket io, we can send acknowledgement to the client with

```
@SubscribeMessage('newMessage')
onNewMessage(
  @MessageBody() body: FooDto,
  @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket,
) {
  return 'ok1';
}
```

The Client will receive an acknowledgement with 'ok'

```
socket.emit("newMessage", "foo", (arg1) => {
  console.log(arg1); // "ok1"
});
```

However if I would like to receive multi-param acknowledgement in the client, how to do that in Nest JS

```
socket.emit("newMessage", "foo", (arg1, arg2) => {
  console.log(arg1); // "ok1"
  console.log(arg2); // "ok2"
});
```

I tried the following code and it doesn't work as the ack is undefined. I am using Postman's socket io runtime to test.

```
@SubscribeMessage('newMessage')
onNewMessage(
  socket, [data, ack]
) {
  ack('ok1', 'ok2');
}
```